# circle in container Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a flutter app,

and I need to make a circle in a container in flutter.

I try to create a container and put an image inside it but the circle is to small,

here is my code:

```
Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage("ipage.jpeg),
                    fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                  ),
                ),
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                child: CircleAvatar(backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                  child: Image.network('https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/147/147144.png' , height:150,),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

Please help me how can I do that in flutter

Comment: try to give `radius` as named argument, in your `CircleAvater` widget.

Comment: when I put the radius, the image move up, I want the image in the center of bottom image , how can do that

Comment: Check out [ask] to improve this question

Comment: @Mohamedahmad Please update the question with an image or gif that shows the output after you applied radius.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to your demand you need to use `Stack` here.

This can archive this way

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FFTBuild extends StatelessWidget {
  const FFTBuild({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final mainBoxheight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.9;
    return Container(
      height: mainBoxheight,
      color: Colors.cyanAccent,
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            child: Image.asset(
              "assets/image.jpg",
              height: mainBoxheight * .85,
               width: double.infinity,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: Image.network(
              'https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/147/147144.png',
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              width: 150,
              height: 150,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

But I prefer `LayoutBuilder` instead of using `MediaQuery`

```
class FFTBuild extends StatelessWidget {
  const FFTBuild({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // final mainBoxheight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.9;
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) => Container(
        height: constraints.maxHeight * .4,
        ///I added `Container Color`to clarify the thing,
       // color: Colors.cyanAccent,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
              child: Image.asset(
                "assets/image.jpg",
                height: constraints.maxHeight * .3,
                width: constraints.maxWidth,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: Image.network(
                'https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/147/147144.png',
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                width: 150,
                height: 150,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

you may need to set tweak the value according to your desire. let me know if you need more on it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add radius to the circle avatar and modify circle avatar a bit

```
Container(
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.9,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(
        image: AssetImage("${ImagePath.profileCover}"),
        fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
      ),
    ),
    child: Align(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      child: CircleAvatar(
        radius: 100,//increase or decrease this for the size of your image
        backgroundImage: NetworkImage('https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/147/147144.png'),
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: when I put the radius, the image move up, I want the image in the center of bottom image , how can do that